# Avoid escaping special characters during XML file save

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm using VB.NET to make a program which will have to write data in a XML tag of a specific file.

The line of data I'm willing to write is the following.

```
&lt;Stream&gt;XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX?p=0&lt;/Stream&gt;&lt;URL&gt;rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2&lt;/URL&gt;
```

But what I get in my XML file after writing is pretty different.

```
&amp;lt;Stream&amp;gt;XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX?p=0&amp;lt;/Stream&amp;gt;&amp;lt;URL&amp;gt;rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2&amp;lt;/URL&amp;gt;
```

The &lt and &gt are here for purpose, and are NOT < and >. I need to keep this formatting but when I use the XmlDocument.Save method, it replaces all the & by & amp; (space is here to avoid the automatic formatting of my text...)

I use this code to write data in the xml file.

```
Sub WriteXML()

   Document.Load("path to document")

   Dim Node As XmlNode = Document.SelectSingleNode("XPath to my data")
   If Node IsNot Nothing Then
      Node.InnerText = DATA
   End If

   Document.Save("path to document")

End Sub
```

I do understand it's here to get a correct formating of the written XML document, but I can't manage to write my data as I want...

How can I write my data in a XML document without the escaping for the ampersand?

Comment: Do you control both ends of this, or are you trying to write for a reader that you don't control?  If you control both ends, have you considered using CDATA for the payload?

Comment: In this case, I'm writing in a savefile which will be readed by a program I didn't make... But as the last answer said, I needed to stand back and think a bit... if my line of data contains the <, > and & characters, then it will be formatted as &lt; , &gt; and &amp; ... and it will be the correct formatting for my data in the XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If writing the string `"&lt;"` produces `"&amp;lt;"`

then writing the string `"<"` will produce `"&lt;"`.

Alternatively, stand back and find a better design...

Comment: Thank you, it's a exactly what I thought after a good night of sleep! You're right, just doing a little break and getting back at it after is always a good way to realise it was not so hard...

Comment: If this is the right answer then please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check/tick mark next to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After writing to file, could you just open it back up with a string reader and replace all instances of & with your ampersand?

```
Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("path to document).Replace("&lt;", "&").Replace("&amp;","&")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("new path", fileReader, False)
```

That way, you keep your XML code and just do some basic cleanup.  The only issue is, this isn't valid XML.  The ampersand needs to be written as &, but if it's what you want, you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to avoid the normal special character escaping provided when a *text node* is written to document, you want to ensure that the [XmlWriter.WriteRaw Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeraw?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlWriter_WriteRaw_System_String_) is called to write out the string.

From the above referenced method's Remarks:

> This method does not escape special characters.

I specifically stated *text node* as this is something many do not fully grasp; the text is itself a node in the element.

From: [XML DOM - The Element Object](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_element.asp)(emphasis added)

> The Element object represents an element in an XML document. Elements
>   may contain attributes, other elements, or text. If an element
>   contains text, the text is represented in a text-node.
>
> IMPORTANT! **Text is always stored in text nodes. A common error in DOM
>   processing is to navigate to an element node and expect it to contain
>   the text.** However, even the simplest element node has a text node
>   under it. For example, in 2005, there is an element node
>   (year), and a text node under it, which contains the text (2005).

A text node is an instance of the [XmlText Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). All XmlNode instances support [XmlNode.WriteTo(XmlWriter) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.writeto?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlNode_WriteTo_System_Xml_XmlWriter_) that is used to write a node's data to an `XmlWriter`.  If we look at [this method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlText.cs,3fae5720f9749b25) (converted to VB), we see that it calls the [WriteString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring?view=netframework-4.7.2) that escapes special character.

```
' Saves the node to the specified XmlWriter.
Public Overrides Sub WriteTo(ByVal w As XmlWriter)
    w.WriteString(Data)
End Sub
```

Therefore if we create a class derived from XmlText, we can override this method to use the `WriteRaw` method.

```
Public Class RawXMLText : Inherits XmlText
    Public Sub New(data As String, doc As XmlDocument)
        MyBase.New(data, doc)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub WriteTo(w As XmlWriter)
        w.WriteRaw(Me.Data)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now to use the `RawXMLText` class to create a node that will write the un-escaped string (raw).

```
Dim raw As String = "&lt;Stream&gt;XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX?p=0&lt;/Stream&gt;&lt;URL&gt;rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2&lt;/URL&gt;"
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load(**pathToDocument**)

' 1st get the containing element
Dim elementWithTextToChange As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("xpath to element")

' attempt to retrieve the child text node. will be null if there is no text
Dim possibleTextNode As XmlText = CType(elementWithTextToChange.SelectSingleNode("child::text()"), XmlText)

If possibleTextNode Is Nothing Then
    'create and add RawXMLText
    elementWithTextToChange.AppendChild(New RawXMLText(raw, doc))
Else
    ' replace existing XMLText with RawXMLText
    elementWithTextToChange.ReplaceChild(New RawXMLText(raw, doc), possibleTextNode)
End If
doc.Save(**pathToSaveTo**)
```